# Why vue-jest doesn't install Bootstrap-vue correctly in my test file?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, bootstrap-vue

Thank you by advance for your answer !!

Here my problem : i want to do unit test with Jest.

And i test my component ( a login form) and i use in this component : Bootstrap-vue.
So in my test file, i include Bootrap-vue, createLocalVue from vue-test-utils.

But i get an error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'installed' of undefined

```
  12 | Vue.use(Vuetify);
  13 | localVue.use(VueAxios,axios);
> 14 | localVue.use(BootstrapVue);
     |          ^
  15 | localVue.use(IconsPlugin);
  16 | 
  17 | 

  at Function.use (node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:13742:16)
  at Object.<anonymous> (test/unit/specs/components/form/login.spec.js:14:10)
```

Here my file login.spec.js (test file) :

```
import 'es6-promise/auto';
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import axios from 'axios';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue, mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin  } from 'bootstrap-vue';

import FormLogin from '@/components/Form/login';

const localVue = createLocalVue();
Vue.use(Vuetify);
localVue.use(VueAxios,axios);
localVue.use(BootstrapVue);
localVue.use(IconsPlugin);


let wrapper = null;



describe('FormLogin', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        const vuetify = new Vuetify();

        wrapper = shallowMount(FormLogin,{
            localVue,
            vuetify
        });
    });
    
    afterEach(() => {
        wrapper.destroy();
    });
    
    it('contains input text',() => {
        const type = wrapper.find('input').map((node) =>node.props().type);
        const text = type.filter((e) => e === 'text').length === 1;
        expect(text).toBe(true);
    });

    it('contains input password',() => {
        const type = wrapper.find('input').map((node) =>node.props().type);
        const password = type.filter((e) => e === 'password').length === 1;
        expect(password).toBe(true);
    });

    it('contains button', () => {
        expect(wrapper.find('button').toBe(true));    
    })
});
```

And my config files :

jest.config.js :

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  rootDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../'),
  setupFiles: ['setup.js'],
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'json',
    'vue',
    'ts'
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    'vue$': "vue/dist/vue.common.js",
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
    '.*\\.(vue)$': 'vue-jest'
  },
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/test/coverage/',
    '<rootDir>/dist/',
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/'
  ],
  //snapshotSerializers: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-serializer-vue'],
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/test/unit/setup'],
  coverageDirectory: '<rootDir>/test/unit/coverage',
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'src/**/*.{js,vue}',
    '!src/main.js',
    '!src/router/index.js',
    '!**/node_modules/**'
  ],
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/core.js','node_modules/babel-runtime','node_modules/vue',"node_modules/(?!bootstrap-vue)"]
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-flow",
      "@babel/preset-react",
    
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
      /*{
        "modules": false,
        "targets": {
          "browsers": [
            "> 1%",
            "last 2 versions",
            "not ie <= 8"
          ]
        }
      }*/
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-vue-jsx",
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "corejs": 2
      }
    ],
    "babel-plugin-styled-components",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings",
    "transform-class-properties",
  "syntax-class-properties",
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        "legacy": true
      }
    ],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions"
  ]
}
```

I searched for more 1 week but i did'nt find the same problem of mine. Or it wasn't the good solution. I tried to delete my node_modules and to re-install and it is the same problem.

I thank you for your answer.

Have a good day !!

Comment: Make sure the error refers to `localVue.use(BootstrapVue)` line and not adjacent ones. There seems to be no way how `install` in `install.installed` can be undefined in bootstrap-vue, at least for current release, make sure you're using the latest. Also, why `Vue.use(Vuetify)` and not `localVue`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I use Vue.use(Vuetify) because localVue.use(Vuetify) gave me an error.
I am sure it is BootstrapVue because when i console.log in my main.js (file execute when the server is running), install.installed exists and not in my file test.
I use the last version of vue and bootstrap, i installed this morning.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There are several `use` calls, each of them can trigger this error because `installed` property is specific to Vue plugins in general (also this error shouldn't occur in well-written plugin, there's no way how `install` can become undefined here https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/dev/src/utils/plugins.js#L34-L49 ). Jest could point at the wrong line because of source map problems. You need to reliably narrow down the problem to specific plugin for starters.

Comment: btu for vuetify, and vuex it works. How do i know which plugin doesn't work ? Instead Bootstrap if i understand that you mean

Comment: How do you know that it really works? Comment them all and uncomment one by one. Currently you're the only person who can do that. The problem is currently cannot be recognized by other users because seems to be no possibility how bootstrap-vue can trigger this error, see the link above. If the problem persists, please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can be reproduced by other users who don't have access to your project.

Comment: Thank you for your time, i test and i will write my solution if i succeed in resolve my problem

Comment: I tried your solution but when i decomment localVue.use(BootstrapVue), the error appears. I think i will create another project and test only bootstrapVue, i will see. Strange !!

Comment: Okay so my solution, it was to create another project and i installed jest and bootstrapVue. I tested HelloWorld.spec.js with bootstrap and it worked. So I copyed folder test in my project and it worked. Strange, thank you for your help !!

Comment: Probably node_packages become corrupted somehow. Glad you sorted this out.